# Bundled scripts not rendering properly

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification

I'm getting my feet wet with ASP.NET MVC and I've hit a snag with bundling.

Here are the contents of my BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    "~/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery-ui").Include(
    "~/bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/core.js",
    "~/bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js",
    "~/bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/position.js",
    "~/bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/menu.js",
    "~/bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/autocomplete.js"
));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mondernizr").Include(
    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"
));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "~/Content/PagesList.css",
    "~/Content/Site.css",
    "~/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
));
```

And here is the area in my _Layout html where I want to render the scripts and css in the head.

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquery-ui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

As far as I'm aware I just need to use the same relative path as I specified in the bundles to get it to output either the full list of script/link tags or the bundled version. Instead I get the following without any of the versioning strings at the end that I was expecting.

```
<link href="/Content/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/bundles/jquery"></script>
<script src="/bundles/jquery-ui"></script>
<script src="/bundles/modernizr"></script>
```

This happens regardless if I have BundleTable.EnableOptimizations set to true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following a tutorial for using bower and bundling [here](https://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2014/12/08/Getting-started-with-Bower-on-an-ASPNET-MVC-project), as well as the tutorial from microsoft, [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification). What wasn't explained in either tutorial was that the class has to be called in the Application_Start in the Global.asax.cs file with the following:

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Also I had misspelled modernizr in my configuration as mondernizr.